# Bounding ratio of integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to upper bound the following ratio of integrals:

$$\frac{\int_{1}^a \frac{1}{x} (1  - kx )^d dx}{\int_{1}^b \frac{1}{x} (1  - kx )^d dx}$$

where $a < b$ and $a, b \in (0, 1)$. This integral doesn't have a closed form and $k$ is such that I can't approximate with $(1 - kx)^d \approx \exp(d (-kx))$ ($kx = \Omega(1 / d)$).

Any suggestions on possible techniques to use here?

Comment: Thanks and sorry about the typo.

Comment: Now the integrals' upper endpoints are smaller than their lower endpoints ... is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm not completely understand your question, but there is a closed form, simple e.g.  for k<0  $(-1)^{1+d} \text{Beta}\left[\frac{1}{k x},-d,1+d\right]$,  This function [Wolfram Research](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/26/01/02/0001/) has an inverse, so it is possible to set up a and b for a specific ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Lets define:
$$I(X)=\int_1^X\frac{1}{x}(1-kx)^ddx$$
let $u=kx\Rightarrow dx=du/k$ so:
$$I(X)=\int_{k}^{kX}\frac ku(1-u)^d\frac{du}k=\int_k^{kX}\frac1u(1-u)^ddu$$
now using the fact that $b>a$ we can say that:
$$I(b)=I(a)+\int_{ka}^{kb}\frac1u(1-u)^ddu$$
and what you have is:
$$F=\frac{I(a)}{I(b)}=\frac{I(a)}{I(a)+...}=1-\frac{...}{I(a)+...}$$

where $...$ is the integral outlined above. $1$ is an obvious upper bound but using a series expansion for $(1-u)^d$ there is definitely a better bound.